# Send e-mail when new item is created and when is reasigned

Tags: workflow, email, user

Hello i linked an infopath form to a sharepoint library,

When a new form is created the user must select a user from a drop down list, after he saves the form i want the selected user to receive an e-mail with the link to the document that is saved on my sharepoint library.

After some days users might want to reassign the form to a new user,

Is there a way to send an e-mail to the new assigned user that includes the link to the form?

notice: the option start workflow when item changes is not useful for me because there are more fields that can be changed and are not related to the user assignation.[image]

Comment: Yes you can create a SharePoint designer workflow to trigger it when item is added, on workflow select the column where you have email address stored.     SharePoint Designer workflow also comes up with reassign Capabilities ootb, which does exactly what you are looking for.